# Verbatim style in a sentence

Tags: verbatim

I'd like to write this sentence with a method in LaTeX:

"*if you want to use Math.round method*" and having Math.round in verbatim style. But if I write the code like this:

if you want to use `\begin{verbatim}Math.round\end{verbatim}` method
the sentence is messed up. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: `\texttt{Math.round}`

Answer (score 5):

Inline verbatim is `\verb` but here you just want to select a monospace font so:

```
\texttt{Math.round}
```

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, both `\verb` and `texttt` will present things in a monospace font.

The difference is that the `\verb` construct will not execute whatever code you have in there. If you include code that you want to display in a `\texttt` construct, it will execute the code, rather than display it. So which one you use will depend on whether or not that code will execute.